# JavaScript if variable has indexOf an item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable that is set dynamically on the page. I then have a list of colors in an array. I need to see if the color variable contains one of the items within the array.

Here's the code:

```
var colorlist = ['Silver', 'Gray', 'Black', 'Red', 'Purple', 'White'];
var col1 = "";
var color1 = 'Titanium Silver';
for (var c = 0; c < colorlist.length; c++) 
{
    if(color1.indexOf(colorlist[c]))
    {
        col1 = colorlist[c];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

What I would expect this to return is "Silver", but it's consistently returning the last item in the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using a string, remember that IE<9 doesn't have `indexOf` you  may want to use `search`

Comment: I tested in IE 7+ and it's all working just fine.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: it doesn't have `Array.indexOf`, but `String.indexOf` is fine.

Comment: That's correct, I tried to say that you should be careful with arrays and wrote gibberish. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your comparison to:

```
if(color1.indexOf(colorlist[c]) > -1)
```

`-1` is returned when an item isn't found, yet `-1` is truthy. The only falsey number is `0`. So your comparison won't work as you expect.

Take a look at this fiddle, which prints the result of the `indexOf` and the truthyness of the value: http://jsfiddle.net/R3Xb3/

Notice how the first one returns `true` because "Silver" is found in the string (at a valid index). But then the rest aren't found, the index returned is `-1`, and the result is `true`.

Comment: So why would OP's loop return the last element?

Comment: @tymeJV Because the rest of the items in the array would return `-1`, which is truthy. And the OP doesn't `break` in the loop, so it continues

Comment: Stupid me! How did I miss that part! That's what happens when I stare at the same code for far too long. Thanks!